# siunitx not found in texlive

Tags: siunitx

I am aware that some problems occur when installing livetex with the ubuntu package manager (such as this one https://askubuntu.com/questions/369268/missing-sty-package) but I installed livetex with the script provided from the website (https://www.tug.org/texlive/acquire-netinstall.html) and installed all packages and I can verify that siunitx is present in my machine

```
 jordi@desktop  /usr/local  find . -name "siunitx.sty"
./texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/siunitx/siunitx.sty
```

However when compiling something with pdflatex it complains that siunitx cant be found, and also other packages like circuitikz.

```
! LaTeX Error: File `siunitx.sty' not found.

Type X to quit or <RETURN> to proceed,
or enter new name. (Default extension: sty)

Enter file name:
```

What is the problem?

Comment: You most likely have two latex installations. How did yuo add the one you installed tvia a script to your PATH (it is not automatically added), plus what does `which latex` give in a terminal?

Comment: I used the option to add symbolic links to `/usr/local/bin` The output of `which latex` gives  `/usr/bin/latex`

Comment: I would not recommend adding symlinks as you probably forget about it later. As you can see latex is not pointing to `/usr/local/bin` thus you have two latex installations. Your system will choose the "bad" one as `/usr/bin/ comes before `/usr/local/bin` in the PATH.

Comment: How can I fix it? Should I delete the "wrong" binaries from `/usr/bin`

Comment: Add `/usr/local/texlive/2019/bin/x86_64-linux` to the front of your `PATH` variable. To just test it in a terminal try: `export PATH=/usr/local/texlive/2019/bin/x86_64-linux:$PATH` (note the colon, **very important**). Then run `which latex` afterwards.

Comment: The command "find" is not relevant to identify the siunit.sty. You must type "kpsewhich siunitx.sty" to check if the package siunitx is active. If not  you shoud check your TeXLive installation. It can be a PATH problem or a package installation problem. You can reinstall the texlive-science package

Comment: @gigiair yes and no. Find is  relevant here to show that the file exists. But then as you mention kpsewhich will reveal that the active latex installation cannot find it.

Comment: @daleif The presence of a siunitx.sty file which is not in the kpathsea search path is of no great interest for this problem, except to presume the probability of a faulty installation.

Comment: @gigiair that is debatable since the OP had already installed upsteam TL.

Comment: I was able to fix it by changing the PATH variable